# plaise help me i am new in unity 2d i ahve this error

Tags: unity-game-engine

[error CS0426: The nested type `CapFunction' does not exist in the type`UnityEditor.Handles'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrUPy.png)

Comment: Don't use screenshots. image links can go bad and often render poorly for mobile. Paste your code directly into the question. You can specify the language coloring by adding "<!-- language: [the computer language] -->" above it, and put it into a code block by indenting each line 4 spaces.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Comment: First of all - use right tags. `unity-container` is not `unity3d`

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Unity are you using? The Handles class didn't contain a `CapFunction` delegate until v5.5, before which it only had `DrawCapFunction`, and before v5.0 there was no delegate function at all.

When you create a delegate instance in a variable and assign it a value, you need to use the `new` keyword to create an instance of the delegate type. So your line 78 should look like:

```
public Handles.CapFunction controlPointsCap = 
    new Handles.CapFunction(Handles.CircleHandleCap);
```

See [this article on delegates in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx?printable=true).